# React axios-auth-refresh Handle Refresh token API Expiry

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, refresh-token

I am using [axios-auth-refresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-auth-refresh) library.

My use case is,

1. If the request (Let's say getCourse) is getting 401 Error, I will Invoke `RefreshToken` API.
2. With the response of `RefreshToken` API, I will again consume the original request.
3. If Refresh token is expired, I will throw 'Refresh Token Invalid' in 403 Http Status code.
4. If I get 403 in `RefreshToken` API, I will show a sweet alert for 5 seconds and remove all the local storage and reload the window(Signout).

My problem is when `RefreshToken` API response is expired, The error response of Original API(getCourse) is sent to the `getCourse` invoke call. But I don't want to send `getCourse` failure API response if `RefreshToken` API is failed.

[image]
Here is my code,

```
import axios from "axios";
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor from 'axios-auth-refresh';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL });

API.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = getToken() || "";
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );


  // Function that will be called to refresh authorization
const refreshAuthLogic = async failedRequest => {
    // console.log('failedRequest', failedRequest);
    return API.post("/refresh-token", {
      token: getRefreshToken("refresh_token"),
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const { token, refreshToken } = response.data;
      setToken(token);
      setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
      // err.response.config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // console.log('error', err)
      removeLocalStorageData();
      fireSessionTimeoutAlert(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
    
  }


  // Instantiate the interceptor
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(API, refreshAuthLogic);
```

Why My original requests don't waiting until I get the catch response of `RefreshToken` API?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing the right thing, and this pattern means up to 3 callbacks per API request. It works best with async await syntax, leading to simpler code:

- [Single Page App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts)
- [Android App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt)
- [iOS App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Api/Client/ApiClient.swift)

A couple of suggestions:

- I suspect your problem is related to `callback hell` and moving to async await might enable you to resolve it due to a single outer catch block.
- I quite like a `service agent` pattern since the rest of the app doesn't need to know anything about axios. Also, if interceptors in a particular tech stack are causing problems, you have other options for dealing with it.

I showed some mobile code above to indicate that you don't have to use particular library features such as interceptors. Personally I like patterns that are portable.